# Why use JSF 1.2 over JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

when searching for solutions to problems I have writing a JSF 2.0 application, 99% of the questions and answers refer to JSF 1.2

I know there are differences (ie. a lot of nav rules in 1.2 use a special xml file, and 2.0 doesn't do that)

is there a reason that most people seem to be using 1.2? is it better, is JSF 2.0 too new and no one knows anything about it?

Comment: it's just time-lag and necessity. _Your platform needs to support it or you're working on a legacy app or you need 3rd party code that isn't compatible._ I was still writing Java 1.3 code long after Java 5 came out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java EE world, business companies upgrade relatively slow. It's not uncommon that they only upgrade when the **maturity** of a new technology has proven itself after one or two years or even more. JSF 1.0 was also by almost everyone skipped. Most started with JSF 1.1 or 1.2 only. Also, JSF 1.2 existed for relatively a long time, that's why most of the *existing* JSF questions/answers concerns JSF 1.2. However, currently I see here at Stackoverflow a trend that more and more JSF 2.0 questions are been asked and answered as compared to JSF 1.x.

If you have a JSF 2.0 specific issue for which you can't find an answer yet, just ask it here. This way we can build together towards a great knowledge base. That's where Stackoverflow is all about. If you explore/search the [jsf-2.0](/questions/tagged/jsf-2.0) tag and the [frequently asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf-2.0/faq), you'll find several great JSF 2.0 specific questions and answers.

My recommendation would be, stick to JSF 2.0. It's so *much* better than JSF 1.2.

Comment: awesome thank you, I will ask more questions here from now on if I can't find what I need, I just signed up finally after visiting the site many times in the past, and was starting to get frustrated with the lack of JSF 2.0 info I could find on the rest of the web